# Passar valor de um array json para uma variável

Tags: javascript, android, html5, apache-cordova

Estou criando um aplicativo para Android e estou tentando passar de um *array* JSON um elemento chamado `phoneNumber`, e estou utilizando esse plugin abaixo, que traz esse elemento no *array*: [TelephoneNumberPlugin](https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin)
porém o código que estou modelando é da seguida forma:

```
 <script type="javascript">document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);function onDeviceReady(){window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);}function successCallback(result) {document.getElementById("tesouro").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);}function errorCallback(error) {document.getElementById("tesouro").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);}</script><a onclick="ph()">clique</a><p id="nada"></p>
```

Comment: Ficou pouco claro pra mim o que você precisa e o que você tentou fazer @JonathanSilva. Poderia dar algum exemplo?

Comment: Sim, o plugin que estou utilizando oferece o recurso de transformar as informações do SIM em um JSON, um dos elementos é o phoneNumber. por meio de um evento onclick, gostaria de trazer o valor de phoneNumber como um resultado. mas não estou conseguindo trazer esse valor.